# Matching Game Revealing Tiles and Accidently Winning

Tags: c#, random, picturebox

I'm very sorry to have to ask for your help again so soon, but this is the last piece for my classwork.

Basically in this part of this quiz, I've designed it so that the player matches two picture-boxes together, whenever a player clicks a box it reveals the first image, whenever the player clicks on the second box, if the tags match, the two boxes will stay visible and the player will then proceed until all pairs have been matched.

My problems are that, upon entering the form, all of the picture boxes are visible, which simply won't do. And the second, and perhaps most frustrating of all is that, whenever I click any picturebox on ANY other picturebox, the game ends, and I get an unhandled NullReferenceException that refers to the TimerClick_Tick event.

I would sincerely appreciate it if someone could assist me, or at the very least steer me in the correct direction towards fixing my errors.

Thank you for your time.

```
private void pbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TimerClick.Enabled == true)
            return;

        PictureBox clickedPBox = sender as PictureBox;

        if (clickedPBox != null)
        {
            if (clickedPBox.ForeColor == Color.Transparent)
                return;

            if (FirstClickedBox == null)
            {
                FirstClickedBox = clickedPBox;
                FirstClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
                return;
            }

            SecondClickedBox = clickedPBox;
            SecondClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;

            CheckingForWinner();

            if (FirstClickedBox.Tag == SecondClickedBox.Tag)
            {
                FirstClickedBox = null;
                SecondClickedBox = null;
                return;
            }

            TimerClick.Start();
        }
    }

    private void TimerClick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
        SecondClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;

        FirstClickedBox = null;
        SecondClickedBox = null;
    }

    private void CheckingForWinner()
    {

        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            PictureBox iconBox = control as PictureBox;

            if (iconBox != null)
            {
                if (iconBox.ForeColor == iconBox.BackColor)
                    return;

            }



        }

        HasGameBeenWon = true;
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully matched all of the above icons!", "We congratulate you!");
        CurrentPlayer.CurrentPlayerScore += 10;
        CurrentPlayer.CheckHardMode = true;
        CurrentPlayer.HardModeHasBeenChecked = false;
        Close();

    }

    int counter = 60;
    private void frmQuizThreeHardMode_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 60;
        TimerEnd = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        TimerEnd.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEnd_Tick);
        TimerEnd.Interval = 1000;
        TimerEnd.Start();
        textBox1.Text = counter.ToString() + " seconds";
    }

    private void TimerEnd_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter--;
        if ((counter <= 60) && (counter != 0))
        {
            textBox1.Text = counter.ToString() + " seconds";

            if ((counter < 1) && (HasGameBeenWon == false))
            {
                TimerEnd.Stop();
                textBox1.Text = "Time's up!";
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't finish in time. 10 points will be deducted from your total.", "You're Too Slow!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                this.Close();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: It sounds as though you have multiple problems described in your question. I would be sure the break them up and address them one by one. Perhaps start with what might be the simplest: "all of the picture boxes are visible", which might be resolved by setting each controls' Visible property to false

Comment: I have solved the visibility problem, however I may have created another problem, that in which I cannot make them visible again when I click.

Answer (score 2):

The **NullReferenceException that refers to the TimerClick_Tick event**

Probably means just that - the exception, is coming from this code:

```
private void TimerClick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FirstClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
    SecondClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;

    FirstClickedBox = null;
    SecondClickedBox = null;
}
```

It might appear to be related to clicking something, but this could be by coincidence...

Your code sets FirstClickedBox and SecondClickedBox to NULL, perhaps the first time that the event fires, this code runs okay, but because these references have been wiped out; when the code runs for a second time         *FirstClickedBox.ForeColor = Color.Transparent* cannot run because *FirstClickedBox* has been set to null?

You could verify this by placing a breakpoint in the Tick event or outputting a debug message if you are not using an IDE with interactive debugging.